# LINQ to Objects - NOT IN query

Tags: linq

I have two string arrays (let call them “AllEmployees”, and “ActiveEmployees”) that I’d like to compare with LINQ to find all inactive employees (basically all those in AllEmployees that aren’t in ActiveEmployees.

How can I do that using LinQ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about?:

```
var inactiveEmployees = AllEmployees.Except(ActiveEmployees);
```

[System.Linq.Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)